# Anime with a wolf/man demon as main character

Tags: inuyasha

A friend of mine is looking for an anime with a wolf/man or dog/man as main character. He described him as a demon with a red cloak and a big sword. He has long white hair and protects a female girl with black hair. The story takes place in old days from Japan, but I think the girl came from modern times.

I know which anime he means, but I can't remember its name. I hope some of you can help me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is it possible that you're searching for [InuYasha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inu_Yasha)?

Comment: @MCeley (who maybe won't read this): Thanks for editing. My English isn't the best.

Comment: @looper Not a problem. Here to help!